# Get TableRow array class from DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to convert the code below to a `TableRow[]` array using LINQ and add it to a main `Table` class.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    tr.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "setMouseOverColor(this);");
    tr.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "setMouseOutColor(this);");
    tr.Attributes.Add("onclick", "selectRow(this);");
    TableCell td = new TableCell();
    td.Text = dr["Test"].ToString();
    tr.Cells.Add(td);
    table.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```

Is there a way in LINQ to achieve this without going through a `foreach` loop?

I was able to write a `TableCell[]` array class as:

```
TableCell[] tdarr = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(p => new TableCell { Text = p.Field<string>("Test") }).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Learner, I don't need to convert to DataTable. I already have DataTable which i want to loop through each record to create html Table structure. In that DataTable I've one column. I want to create Table cell with DataTable column value and then add that Table cell to Table row and then to Html Table class. Hope its clear for you now.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Deleted my comment.

Comment: I guess even if you use LINQ, you will still have to use ForEach. If I am not wrong, what you need is to map your datatable directly to HTML table not sure if there is any sort of object to HTML table mapper available.